# Updating team email signatures through Gsuite/Workspace store?

Tags: python, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm trying to make a Gsuite/Workspace store app, that allows organizations to update their employee signatures. I'm running into some complications - I feel that Google API doc isn't really doing the job

## Goal

When an admin of an organization authenticates their Google account we want to update one of the domain's email's signatures.

## Attempt 1 - use admin token

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google.auth import impersonated_credentials

SCOPES_USER = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing',
]

email = 'user_email@without_admin.access'

service = build(
    'admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)

users = (
    service.users().
    list(customer='my_customer', maxResults=100).
    execute()['users'])
   
for user in users:
    if user['primaryEmail'] == email:
        user_id = user['id']
        email = user['primaryEmail']

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

# Here it fails
service.users().settings().sendAs().\
    patch(userId=user_id,
          sendAsEmail=email,
          body=dict(signature='Awesome Signature')).execute()
```

The error is as follows:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting
> https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users//settings/sendAs/user_email@without_admin.access?alt=json
> returned "Delegation denied for admin@email.com". Details:
> "[{'message': 'Delegation denied for admin@email.com', 'domain':
> 'global', 'reason': 'forbidden'}]">

## Attempt 2 - Use impersonate the token

Exactly the same code with just one change. I have a full code example just to help as a reference.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google.auth import impersonated_credentials

SCOPES_USER = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing',
]

email = 'user_email@without_admin.access'

service = build(
    'admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)

users = (
    service.users().
    list(customer='my_customer', maxResults=100).
    execute()['users'])
   
for user in users:
    if user['primaryEmail'] == email:
        user_id = user['id']
        email = user['primaryEmail']

# This is the only difference.
creds = impersonated_credentials.Credentials(
    source_credentials=creds,
    target_principal=email,
    target_scopes=SCOPES_USER,
    lifetime=500)
   
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

# Here it fails
service.users().settings().sendAs().\
    patch(userId=user_id,
          sendAsEmail=email,
          body=dict(signature='Awesome Signature')).execute()
```

Results as below:

```
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
```

> google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('Unable to acquire impersonated
> credentials: No access token or invalid expiration in response.', '{\n
> "error": {\n    "code": 403,\n    "message": "Request had insufficient
> authentication scopes.",\n    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"\n
> }\n}\n')

## Background info - How keys was authorized (probably not relevant)

Admin scopes was gathered using

```
SCOPES_ADMIN = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.customer',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.alias',
]
```

Comment: I don’t believe what you’re describing is possible, and probably for good reason. What if a malicious actor or rogue admin was able to insert offensive language or images into everyone’s signature? It violates the implicit principle of ensuring that messages and their contents are comprised solely of content from the sender themselves.

Comment: @neuron It is possible, I have tried a tool that does exactly what I'm trying to do, and I've seen other apps in the Gsuite store that offers the same feature.

(one: https://support.xink.io/support/solutions/articles/1000157767-how-to-update-the-email-signature-for-gmail-)

Comment: I think you wanted to @esqew ;)